# Illustrator: how to make a CPU fan graphic?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, effects

What I want to do is create a CPU fan which I will then import into After Effects and have it spining, therefore symmetry is very important. The picture below shows what I am trying to achieve.

I've tried using the 'twist' effect however that distorts the circle and makes the lines appear at inconsistent angles.

[image]

Comment: Select the outer points and rotate. Or inner... Which ever is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Lasso tool <kbd>Q</kbd> drag your mouse around the smaller circle to select the inner points of the lines. Rotate until you get the desired effect.

[image]